# Need help importing animated treads into Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity, curve-modifier

I have been working with blender for a little under 3 months and I am trying to get some animated models into Unity. I was working on the treads of a conveyor belt. I want the model to sit completely still while everything rotates around simultaneously. For the treads I followed the first half of this tutorial: [[2.79] Blender Tutorial: Tank Tracks Animation for Beginners.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiG4--fKVps)

Essentially I have a cube with an array modifier applied and then put a Curve modifier on the Cube array. In order to keep the track stationary I did something different from the tutorial: namely, I move the cube which rotates the array around the curve endlessly.

[An example of the conveyor belt and how modifiers affect it in Blender.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1045556425256087673/1104225877371408454/Untitled_video_-_Made_with_Clipchamp.gif)

It works and looks great...so long as I don't apply the curve modifier. At that point, it begins moving with no tread-like rotation at all. This presents a problem as the Exporting process into Unity seems to automatically apply the Curve modifier. It gets added in and goes off on its own much like in the video above. I've tried applying constraints, but I'm afraid I don't know as much. Even when constraints are applied, the rotating effect just up an vanishes. What should I do?

---

On another note, I also wanted to achieve the appearance of all of the individual objects rotating simultaneously. How would I combine them all into one action instead of several seperate actions?

Thanks for any help!